# How to embed Twitch Object in React component without calling New on every render?

Tags: reactjs, render, embed, reusability, twitch

My component has a function for rendering our Twitch embed. I'm trying to understand how to re-use the created Twitch.Embed without call New each time the component is rendered.

Here is the Twitch provided code to create the embed:

```
    <div id="twitch-embed"></div>

    new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
        width: 854,
        height: 480,
        channel: "monstercat",
        // Only needed if this page is going to be embedded on other websites
        parent: ["embed.example.com", "othersite.example.com"]
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to create Twitch object, using "new" out of Component body:

`const twitchObj = new Twitch.embed({ id: "twitch-embed", .... });`

`const Component = () => {`
 `return (<div id="twitch-embed"></div>);`
`}`

Or even you can create separate file that will provide constructor for creating Twitch object with needed parameters (and maybe with some default values to create predefined object) and then you'll be able import it and create Twitch object everywhere you need.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! the call to TwitchEmbed needs the id of an existing div. Maybe you are right to create a separate component for this and import it into my component?

Comment: My bad, was sleepy)) yes, sure, you can pass id as a parameter, and then use embedded objeck everywhere this id can appear.